# RegEx in python, not sure what I am doing wrong

Tags: python, regex, urllib, findall

I am quite new to Python and I researched as much as I could before I decided I should ask a question here. So here is the problem:

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with my RegEx. I wanted to try the re.findall() out, so I thought I would write a small script that would find phone numbers on webpages. Here is the code that I have right now.

```
    import re, urllib
    inurl = raw_input("Input a URL: ")
    web = urllib.urlopen(inurl)
    web.readlines()

    numbers = re.findall("/\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}/g", web)
    for itm in numbers
        print itm
```

Not sure what is happening. I keep getting the error of "expected string or buffer" for the line that has

```
    numbers = re.findall(".....", web)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to drop the forward slashes and the g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}/g` - The `/../` part is to identify regex in other languages like Ruby and g is a flag, also not applicable to Python. Try removing them and use just `\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}`

Also I think you wanted to use the output / response in the findall and not just web, which is why you are seeing the `expected string or buffer`. You should also remove the line that just does `web.readlines()`

So what you may want to do will be something like this:

```
numbers = re.findall("\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}", web.read())
```

Comment: you just fixed my problem, that was it. Thank you so much. I used a regex generator. I had no idea that the Ruby was in there. Thank you. I have a question. I thought the readlines() would read all the lines and then put it into a list... or did I miss read it at doc.python.org? lol

I will re-read the documentation, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```
"\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}" write raw string r"\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}"
```